# How to pass a variable into a file path in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to pass a user entered company into a path to determine the content displayed.  I have the company submitting to the page that the form is on and this as the path for the content display.  I would like to include a mkdir if it is a new company name.

```
$path = '(uploadedFiles/($_POST['companyName']))';
$dirs = scandir($path);
```

Not sure why but I am now getting an undefined index error.  Here is the portion that is asking for the name it is on the page named admin.php

```
print '<form action="admin.php" method="POST">'.PHP_EOL;
            print' <h4> Enter the name of the company the new uploads belong to.</h4>';
            print'    <label class="control-label"    `for="companyName">companyName</label>';`
            print'      <input type="text" name="" id="companyName" placeholder="Enter Comapny Name ">';
            print'      <button type="submit" class="btn">Enter</button>';
            print' </div>';
```

Comment: Please don’t pass unsanitized user data to things like file paths. They can easily be manipulated by nefarious users.

Comment: And please learn some syntax _basics_ first. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.  I just started learning PHP and yes I had a typo when my finger slipped of the shift key.  I will keep efforting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way (Zend Code Style Guide) is to concat it like this:

```
$path = 'uploadedFiles/' . $_POST['companyName']; // works with double-
                                                  // and single-quotes
```

But be warned: Accepting user input, non-validated into your system can result in hacking attempts.

Another way would be like this:

```
$path = "uploadedFiles/{$_POST['companyName']}"; // double-quotes only
```

Comment: Thanks that works.  The people that will have access to this will have Admin Rights.  So they will already have to have passed through the verification process.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$companynamedir = $_POST['companyName'];

$path = "uploadedFiles/" . $companynamedir;

$dirs = scandir($path);
```

Comment: Might I ask why waste memory by assigning the extra useless variable `$companynamedir` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - "waste memory"? .. Can you specify how much memory is wasted. And if checks need to be done to the POST variable, you are likely to add the extra memory right there.

Comment: It has some disadvantages regarding Big Data or long running Scripts w/o garbage collector, and it makes the code less readable if you have lots of extra variables. But you are completely right with that last point!

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I agree that integration makes code more compact, but I do not agree that this makes a code better readable pre definition. In my opinion it is a choice between a multitude of factors where it comes to editability and functionality. You are absolutely right to consideration of the namespace clutter, but that is another topic.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use double-quotes to process the variable, and the variable is $_POST, not $-POST.

```
$path = "uploadedFiles/{$_POST['companyName']}";
```

Of course, this is a BAD BAD BAD idea to use the POST variable here

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on

Comment: Oh. Right. Duh. Forgot to bracket off the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Added to errors said before ($_POST, not $-POST; mix quotes and double-quotes) you can echo a variable into a string using braces:

```
$path = "uploadedFiles/{$_POST['companyName']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'uploadedFiles/'. $_POST['companyName'] ;
if (!file_exists($path) {
    mkdir($path, 0775, true);
   }
$dirs = scandir($path);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: at least explain the  -1 if you're going to do it.

Comment: 1) The first path assignment isn't going to work (parantheses in path, nor will $_POST['companyName'] get interpolated; single-quotes and it's not a simple variable, so you need to enclose it in {}).  2) the mkdir seems silly in that you're re-building the path that you already tried to store in $path 3) creating a 777 directory randomly is a security nightmare waiting to happen . . .

Comment: path is a string prior to the if statement. there's no validation of its existence as a folder. secondly, no one has addressed the making the directory that the question asked for. all the issues people are referring to arbitray code execution is removed by using the function mkdir. sanitized the code with your code. comments.

Comment: My point with #2 was that instead of rebuilding the path, the mkdir should re-use the variable you created, i.e. `mkdir($path, 0777, true)`.  #3 was more that allowing users to create 777 directories arbitrarily is a bad idea.  Arbitrary execution at this point isn't the issue - the issue is that you're leaving the door wide open for someone to upload a script and run it.  Having directories that are 777 that are accessible to the web server is just bad practice.

Comment: 777 is the default, 775 ?

Comment: ernie--I see your point yet for something that granted had a typo it has generated a long conversation and many responses

Comment: @tomsimo I'm not sure what you're trying to say?  The original response had a major "typo", didn't use the variable, and bad permissions.  I think the comment thread was useful for discussing the issues, and I would hope if someone downvoted one of my answers, they'd explain things to me as well?  How would you have handled it differently?